# how to transfer file between two local computers using grid-ftp

Tags: networking, ftp, grid, file-transfer

I want to do some measurements on file transfer protocols and I installed grid ftp on both computers that I have in lab which are in the same LAN.
I just want to transfer files between these two computers using grid-ftp protocol but when I use this command:
    globus-url-copy sshftp://172.17.20.164/home/username/gridftp/1gbfile file:///home/

it gives me an error and says: error: an end of file was reached
globus_xio: An end of file was reached

172.17.20.164 is ip address for destination computer and 172.17.20.167 is ip for source.
I created end point on globus.org for both of the computers and both of the endpoints statuses are active.
I just don't know how to transfer a file between these two computers using grid-ftp. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thanks